# mosfet to protect reverse plarity from a power suply range 10v-18v DC

Tags: mosfet, pcb-design, circuit-design, power-electronics, circuit-protection

hello I have designed a board that operates on 10v to 18v DC (2A) I need somehow to protect it from reverse polarity, am thinking to use MOSFET but how I can drive the gate in 10v-18v range

Comment: Beat me to it :)

Comment: Perhaps if you cared to add a schematic or picture we could better assess the situation. I find your question a bit vague, missing details.

Answer (score 1):

Use a bridge rectifier, instead.

[image]

Comment: The single mosfet will dissipate less power than a full bridge rectifier.

Comment: Low Vf Schottky diodes may be used to reduce the dissipation.

Comment: True, it will lessen the dissipation, but the single mosfet still wins hands down.